# Unknown Hostname in Perl Socket

Tags: perl

I have written an example perl socket code. Client & server both are running in the same machine. In server code on accepting client connection it is displaying the client hostname as "anates". I dont understand from where it is picking this name. As i have not set this name anywhere.

Server.pl

```
my $client_addr;
while ($client_addr = accept(NEW_SOCKET, SOCKET)) {
   # send them a message, close connection
   print("CCCCLLLII : $client_addr\n");
   my($port2, $iaddr) = sockaddr_in($client_addr);
   print("$port2\n");
   print("$iaddr\n");
   $iaddr = inet_ntoa($iaddr);
   print("$iaddr\n");

   my $name = gethostbyaddr($client_addr, AF_INET );
   print NEW_SOCKET "Smile from the server";
   print "Connection recieved from $name\n";
   close NEW_SOCKET;
}
```

Client.pl

```
connect( SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($server)))
   or die "Can't connect to port $port! \n";

my $line;
while ($line = <SOCKET>) {
   print "$line\n";
}
close SOCKET or die "close: $!";
```

Output:

```
$ perl server.pl 
SERVER started on port 7890
CCCCLLLII : &#x2;�r&#x1;
48498
&#x1;
127.0.0.1
Connection recieved from anantes-158-1-218-114.w2-0.abo.wanadoo.fr

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   kaushik-Inspiron-5547

$ hostname
kaushik-Inspiron-5547
```

From where the code getting the name anates i am not getting.

I was expecting it will print the hostname as kaushik-Inspiron-5547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gethostbyaddr($client_addr, AF_INET)
```

should be

```
gethostbyaddr($iaddr, AF_INET)
```

The garbage you are passing to `gethostbyaddr` is being treated as `2.0.189.114`, and a reverse DNS lookup for that address gives `anantes-158-1-218-114.w2-0.abo.wanadoo.fr`.

---

```
$ perl -MSocket -e'
   my $client_addr = sockaddr_in(48498, inet_aton("127.0.0.1"));
   my ($port, $iaddr) = sockaddr_in($client_addr);
   CORE::say "".gethostbyaddr($client_addr, AF_INET);  # XXX Garbage
   CORE::say "".gethostbyaddr($iaddr, AF_INET);
'
anantes-158-1-218-114.w2-0.abo.wanadoo.fr
localhost
```

Comment: @CodeTag, I have no idea what that comment means